# Combining tables (or kables) without making dataframe

Tags: r, merge

Without making each of these into their own dataframe first, say I have the following data, how can I combine them into one table?

Code for the input:

```
tibble(ResidentName = "Annie", ResidentSec = 27, Room = 46, KGAssessment = 31, OMTest = 88)
tibble(ResidentName = "Oscar", ResidentSec = 52, Room = 93, KGAssessment = 73, OMTest = 18)
tibble(ResidentName = "Cathrine", ResidentSec = 32, Room = 15, KGAssessment = 41, OMTest = 10)
tibble(ResidentName = "Zara", ResidentNum = 71, Room = 85, KGAssessment = 90, OMTest = 42)
```

Input visual:

```
ResidentName    ResidentSec   Room   KGAssessment   OMTest
Annie           27            46     31             88


ResidentName    ResidentSec   Room   KGAssessment   OMTest
Oscar           52            93     73             18


ResidentName    ResidentSec   Room   KGAssessment   OMTest
Cathrine        32            15     41             10

ResidentName    ResidentSec   Room   KGAssessment   OMTest
Zara            71            85     90             42
```

Expected output:

```
ResidentName    ResidentSec   Room   KGAssessment   OMTest
Annie           27            46     31             88
Oscar           52            93     73             18
Cathrine        32            15     41             10
Zara            71            85     90             42
```

I tried rbind with no luck and not sure if there are any other functions out there

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). If those are list of dataframes try `result <- do.call(rbind, list_name)`

Comment: The first grey section is basically four separate tables that were outputted from previous steps in R. But I am hoping to kind of merge them together, so it becomes like the example in my second grey section (i.e. a combined table) without having to make any data frames.

Comment: We don't know the structure of your data, we can guess the structure looking at the grey section but we might guess it wrong which ends up wasting time for both you and us. Please go through the link which I shared earlier and provide us the data in a reproducible format which we can copy into our R session and use it.

Comment: I have updated the question to include more context and the code for input. The original was basically a bunch of read_csv for 400+ csv files from local drive and displayed them as tibble, so not sure if there's anything else to it to show.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code to combine multiple dataframe into one combined dataframe without creating intermediate dataframes.

```
filenames <- list.files(pattern = '\\.csv')
data <- purrr::map_df(filenames, readr::read_csv)
```